# Thinkpad overheating on dock

Tags: thinkpad, dock, cooling

My T-410 overheats while on the dock when performing intensive tasks, such as rendering video. Is there a piece of hardware I can purchase that will actively cool the bottom of the dock? Something more powerful than just a stand with fans built into it (maybe something with some kind of refrigerant looping around inside it).

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question, but are you keeping the laptop lid open while it's on the dock? If not, doing so could help a lot.

Comment: Yup, keep the lid open. See my answer below. I consider this a rather fatal design flaw, because Thinkpads are supposed to be corporate laptops that are extensively used with docks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an external graphics card, ensure your using the onboard intel one if you don't need the graphics power. The PCI Express ones can get really warm.  If your doing video stuff, depending on the encoder, you might not need the GPU, just the CPU.

Also, we have had two T410s's recently (based on the same components) that have had similar problems. The tech that came said there wasn't much thermal paste, but when I called Lenovo and mentioned heat issues, they quickly routed the ticket to another group, which sent out the tech with a new motherboard and stuff.. (although we have onsite support)

Answer (score 0):

The cooling pads sound like a solution except if you have to place the docking station with the laptop together on it. I have a Lenovo-X1 with an overheating problem with very routine tasks and the docking station base extends under the fan vents on the laptop so the cooling action of a pad would be inefficient. A poor, though workable solution, for my docked laptop is to have a very quiet fan (from AC Infinity) sitting on top of the keyboard blowing directly down near the top right-hand side. There is a 3-speed switch on the fan and I can keep the hard drive below 42C at the medium fan speed. Of course this requires that I keep the lid open. Not elegant but seems to work. These inexpensive fans can be ganged together if you need additional pull-push cooling.

Answer (score -1):

Keep the laptop lid open. The cooling air is inducted through the keyboard.

Last week I took my T410 open as it overheated once again and I expected the fan to be full of dust. The fan was clean and the only way it can suck ambient air seems to be from above, that is, through the keyboard assembly.

Sorry for necro-bumping – even though this is an old question, there are still quite a few T410 series devices around as low-end laptops.

Comment: I suspect that by this time, you should also replace your cooling paste. Aftermarket cooling paste is generally of better quality than OEM ones anyway. This should reduce your temperature even further.